# Only retrieve IDs where combination of two rows are FALSE ONLY occur - SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

| ID | Apples | Oranges |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | False | True |
| 1 | False | False |
| 2 | False | False |
| 3 | False | False |
| 3 | False | False |
| 4 | False | False |
| 5 | False | True |
| 5 | False | False |

The output I'm looking for in SQL

| ID | Apples | Oranges |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | False | False |
| 3 | False | False |
| 4 | False | False |

So what SQL query I would want to return is the two rows for ID 2,3 and 4 as they both only have False in Both categories.

Even though 1 & 5 has a False + False combination it is not a distinct combination for that ID. (As they have another combination).

If I do

`WHERE Grocery is False AND Confectionary is False` then ID 1 and 5 also appear which is not what I want.

Any ideas on how I can do this in SQL?

We can assume the table name is called df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select distinct id, apples, oranges
from your_table
qualify not logical_or(apples or oranges) over(partition by id)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: What would you say are the merits of DISTINCT/WINDOW vs standard Aggregate?

Comment: `distinct` Is an implicit aggregation - right? rather than this  - i think this version is more readable, but is matter of preferences :o)

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant could you go into more detail about what the Qualify and Logical_or statement does?

Comment: sure - check out documentation for [SQL syntax](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#sql_syntax) and [QUALIFY clause](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause). Also check function [LOGICAL_OR](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#logical_or)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NOT` operand: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

For the example above it would be:

```
SELECT ID, Apples, Oranges FROM td WHERE NOT(Apples) AND NOT(Oranges)
```

Comment: Please verify my answer if it satisfies your needs.

Comment: This still gives the rows for ID 1 & 5 unfortunately.